# Calling $compile for a directive, outside of the directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

From all the examples I've seen this should work:   (See **EDIT**, I answered my own question.)

```
        .directive('ssmViewport', ['$compile', 'ssmLayoutMan', function($compile, layoutManager) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            replace: false,  // TODO: remove if false is the default.
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                layoutManager.renderView = function (view) {
                        console.log('this text does appear in the log...');
                        element.append('This text should appear...');  // but it doesn't appear
                        // these two commented lines are what I'm really trying to do.
                        //element.append(view.template); 
                        //$compile(element.contents())(scope);
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }])
```

Elsewhere in the code I call:

```
layoutManager.renderView({template: '<div some-custom-directive></div>'});
```

But alas...  the element does not seem to change.  I have tried scope.$apply() after my $compile but it just throws an error about already being in the digest, and still doesn't display changes to the element.

**EDIT:**

I answered my own question.  I will mark a correct answer for anyone who can explain why this is so...

The answer is: 
ssmViewport is a directive that was defined in some markup that was injected like so:

```
var html = $compile(templateThatContainsTheSSMViewport)(scope);
element.html(html);
```

But if I inject it like below, then it will work:

```
element.html(templateThatContainsTheSSMViewport);
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

I just started learning angular yesterday, so I don't understand the difference yet...   Any enlightenment on the issue would be a boon :)

Comment: Where is this call to renderView done? Inside the directive itself right?

Comment: No, renderView is actually called by my $route when the $location changes.  So it is outside the directive.

Comment: Where is the directive define inside or outside `ng-view`. How do you make sure that the directive has already rendered before you start manipulating the element.  Share some html too.

Comment: I don't use ng-view.  My $route is entirely custom and not at all like the default $route provided by angular.  I am confident the directive link function is called before I call "renderView" because I see "this text does appear in the log..." in the log.  I ensure renderView isn't called too early via promises.